# If you uninstall the primary Windows hard drive drivers, are these reinstalled during next boot?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, installation, drivers

I'm having a problem with some partitions in Windows, and I read that reinstalling the drivers may solve the problem, but this is the disk where Windows is installed. If I uninstall the drivers through the device manager, will these be reinstalled on boot?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the drivers without uninstalling first? It would probably be safer. Which version of windows are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can't uninstall it when you are using your Windows, on this sittuation your driver will be schedueled to be deleted on next boot. However, if you uninstall your drivers(doesn't metter from which device) your Windows will boot up with "onboard" generic Windows's drivers( on c:\windows\system32\drivers).

Comment: I did and it loaded the generic drivers (I guess) and detected the failing partitions correctly.

Then I changed the partitions drive names, since they were wrong, and when I restarted again now it doesn't boot, it restarts itself at "Loading windows" without any BSOD.

And the repair tool do nothing. I guess I'll have to reinstall.

Comment: The "Loading Windows" screen still indefinitely?

Comment: The Loading Windows screen freezes for half a second and then the computer restarts.
In any configuration, not even Safe Mode. If I start with the option to prevent Windows from restarting after a crash then a BSOD shows that the problem may be the hard drive drivers. I have access to the system recovery console, but I don't know how to uninstall the hard drive drivers from there =/